# Do mainstream sects of Judaism accept the teachings of likutei mohoran?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, chassidic-rebbe, breslov

I know that there’s a bit of controversy regarding the teachings of Breslov and Likutei Mohoran.

I was wondering if there are mainstream sects of other parts of Judaism that do accept it and if there are mainstream rabbinical figures that accept it as well. Sources would be appreciated.

I heard something along the lines of the Baba Sali always having a copy of Likutei Moharan at his desks but I haven’t seen a source for this.

Was also wondering to learn more about what the exact controversy is surrounding the teachings of R Nachman Mibreslov or his followers.

Comment: https://thelehrhaus.com/scholarship/fed-by-the-waters-of-controversy-r-nahman-of-bratslav-on-the-dynamics-of-dispute/